# What is the meaning of McFaddens Axiom: Irrelevance of Alternative Set Effect?

Tags: probability, self-study, econometrics, multinomial-distribution, extreme-value

On page 110 of *McFadden,1973  - Conditional logit analysis of Qualitative Choice Behavior, Frontiers in Economics, ed Zarembka, New York: Academic Press, pp. 105-142* the following three Axioms are made:

> **Axiom 1: Independence of Irrelevant Alternatives (IIA):**
>
> For all possible sets $B$, measured attributes $s$, and members $x$ and $y$ of
> $B$:
>
> $P(x|s,{x,y})P(y|s,B) = P(y|s,{x,y})P(x|s,B)$

This is essentially the first part of the IIA - Axiome made by Luce, *Luce, R. D. 1959/2005. Individual Choice Behavior: A Theoretical Analysis. New York: Wiley. Reprinted by Dover Publications*

> **Axiom 2: Positivity:**
>
> $P(x|s,B)>0$ for all possbile alternative sets $B$, vectors of
> measured attributes $s$, and $x\in B$.

This is essentially the second part of the IIA - Axiome made by Luce.

Now McFadden does a additional Axiom which says:

> **Axiom 3: Irrelevance of Alternative Set Effekt:**
>
> The function $V(s,x,z)$ determining the selection probabilities in
>
> $P(x|s,B) =\ \frac{e^{V(s,x,z)}}{\sum_{y\in B}e^{V(s,y,z)}}$
>
> has the additively separable form: $V(s,x,z) = v(s,x) - v(s,z)$

Further, he states that Axiom 3 follows from Axiom 1 and 2 if there exsists some "universial benchmark" alternative $z$ such that if $B$ is a possible alternative set, then $B\cup\{z\}$ is also. This follows by noting that Equation (9) holds for $z\not\in B$, provided Axiom 1 and 2 holds for $B\cup\{z\}$. Then, taking $z$ to be the universial benchmark in Equation (10) and defining $v(x,s)=V(s,x,z)$ for all alternative sets yields the result.

Equation (9) $\frac{ p_{yx} }{ p_{xy} } = \frac{ p_{yz}/p_{zy} }{ p_{xz}/p_{zx} }$ follows from Axiom 1 and two where $p_{yx} = P(y|s,{x,y})$ and equation (10) $P(x|s,B) =\ \frac{e^{V(s,x,z)}}{\sum_{y\in B}e^{V(s,y,z)}}$ follows from Axiom 1 and 2 if we set $V(s,x,z) = log(\frac{p_{xz}}{p_{zx}})$

**My question in this context is:** Why do we need this additional assumption, i.e., Axiom 3?

I intuitively understand, that alternative set effects cannot be measured if no replications on the same individual are measured. What I do not understand is, how this *"universal benchmark"* or *"benchmark"* idea is related to this problem?

Will every choice from $B$ be related to some item $z\in B$, which will then be called benchmark?

What does the "*irrelevance"* in this context mean?